# Can I browse all the words in single list view in the Mavericks dictionary?

Tags: macos, dictionary

So I'm riding the Mavericks to a rodeo - OS X 10.9.2 :)

The built-in dictionary is way cool, but is there a way to browse all the words in the dictionary? Like, there will be a list of all words on the left of the screen, from "A" to the very last word, say "zygote (or not^^)". So can I *browse all words*, rather than *look up a certain word*?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do in the built-in Dictionary.app is type a single letter in the search box, like "a" and get a list of up to a 1000 words that begin with it.

You could also write a simple app of your own and use Apple's API for accessing the system dictionaries: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/access/access.html

Comment: That's what I thought too, but there is no way to enumerate through the defined terms. There is nothing in the documented API to get a list of words that start with a string. There is a class called 'DictionaryRecordRepository' that I found in the class-dump of Dictionary.app executable that contains a few promising methods: + (id)recordRepositoryWithSearchString:(id)arg1; in DictionaryRecordRepository but this is private..